# Generate 100 samples for each i of a loop in R

Tags: r, loops

I generated 10 Bernoulli samples of size 2000 each one. I used this command:

```
# Data
samples<-matrix(NA, nrow = 10, ncol = 2000)
for (i in 1:10) {
  samples[i,] <- rbinom(2000, 1, prob = 0.05)
}
```

But now I want to generate 100 Bernoulli samples for each `i` of the loop. All these samples have to be stored at a matrix. I tried this command but I am doing something wrong with me matrix:

```
for (j in 1:100) {
  samples[j,] <- matrix(NA, nrow = 10, ncol = 2000)
  for (i in 1:10) {
    samples[i,] <- replicate(100, rbinom(2000, 1, prob = 0.05))
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Or better yet

```
matrix(rbinom(10*2000,1,prob=0.05),nrow=10,ncol=2000)
```

to generate 2000 cases for each sample, 10 samples in this case.

Comment: Thanks but how can I generate 100 samples for each i and store them all in a big matrix?

Comment: @antonis34 That's not a matrix anymore, that's a 3 dimensional array, I would try to avoid that. I don't understand why you would want that, what is your goal here?